# Visual Studio Code Intellisense select with typing dot

Tags: visual-studio-code

The intellisense of Visual Studio Code at the moment has following behaviour:

1. You type something.
2. Intellisense pops out.
3. The first entry in intellisense is selected.
4. By pressing enter, the suggestion is typed into the editor.
5. Intellisense is closed

In Visual Studio the following behaviour is default:

1. You type something.
2. Intellisense pops out.
3. The first entry in intellisense is selected.
4. By pressing **'.' (Point or Dot)**, the suggestion is typed into the editor.
5. Intellisense is closed

Is there any setting who can change to the Visual Studio behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confirm-with-`.` behavior is the default [since `1.28`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_semicolon-as-a-commit-character-for-jsts). It can be disabled via `editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter` in your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

The confirm-on-`enter` behavior can be toggled [via](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_settings) `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter`:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
```

Be sure that you haven't disable `Enter` hotkey for this, which takes precedence. I.e., open your `keybindings.json` (`Ctrl + Shift + P` → `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts File`), and check that there isn't this:

```
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter",
    "when": "acceptSuggestionOnEnter && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionMakesTextEdit && textInputFocus"
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a hotkey for it yourself as an extra measure, if nothing above works (notice the missing `-` before the command, which differentiates it from the above):

```
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter",
    "when": "acceptSuggestionOnEnter && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionMakesTextEdit && textInputFocus"
}
```

Comment: This worked,but thanks for your work: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60985